# Css Selector for elements with a specific class and parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style an element if it has a specific class and parent element.
If i use `caption > h1` it works perfectly, but a soon as I add my class `.sub` it doesn't work anymore.

**HTML:**

```
<caption>
    <h1 class="sub">Text</h1>
</caption>
```

**CSS:**

***works:***

```
caption > h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #777;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

***doesn't work:***

```
.sub caption > h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #777;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

How is it possible to select elements with a specific `parent` and `class`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `>` selector indicates a **direct** parent. Your above code `.sub caption > h1` is attempting to select any `h1` element that is a direct child of a `caption` element, where the `<caption>` element is a child of an element with the class `.sub`. It is not working because you don't have a **parent** of `<caption>` with the class of `sub`.

You can specify that your target elements **must** contain specific classes by writing the element selector **immediately** followed by the class selector (without a space). For example, `h1.sub` targets any `<h1>` element that has the class `sub`. It **won't** target `<h1>` elements that **don't** have the `.sub` class, **nor** elements that are **not** `<h1>` elements but **do** have the `.sub` class.

It's also important to note that `<caption>` is [only valid as a direct child of `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption).

Essentially, what you're looking for is the following:

```css
caption > h1.sub {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    <h1 class="sub">Text</h1>
  </caption>
</table>
```

This targets any `<h1>` element with the class of `.sub` that is a direct child of `<caption>`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: _"The > selector indicates a direct parent."_ No, the `>` selector is the child selector. And using "direct" with both child and parent is incorrect. If something is a child or parent, it means one level only. Direct descendant or direct ancestor implies the same and would be valid, but it's not with parent or child.

Comment: The `>` is a child selector, and indicates a direct child, but it **also** indicates a direct parent (that is to say, a parent rather than a grandparent). A child must have a direct parent, and I was simply referring to the other side of the relationship. There is no parent selector in CSS, and I apologise for any confusion raised in that regard. By **direct** I also mean that it will only work for the first level. `caption h1` would be valid for `<caption><span><h1>`, though `caption > h1` would not target the `<h1>` given that HTML structure.

Comment: Yes, it also indicates a **parent** relationship but my issue is really with your use of **direct** (grammar nazi type peeve). Something is either a parent or it's not. There's no such thing as a "direct parent". Direct ancestor could possible describe a parent. Sort of like "revert back" there's only one way to revert.